# Refining selectors in Cypress

Tags: jquery-selectors, cypress, custom-selectors

I'm trying to learn best practice for selectors using Cypress.

I have an element buried within many tables within a frame. This is an app I have no control over so cannot add custom selectors for Cypress. The full Xpath is as follows:

`/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a`

Within the `a` tag is the link I wish to do a `click()` on.

`<a class="menubuttontext" style="cursor:pointer" href="javascript:menuClick(1)">Men's Apparel</a>`

Can someone provide the 'best' (or at least relatively resilient) selector?  I don't wish to fall back to adding Xpath libraries - I am switching from many years working with Selenium so learning as I go.  I'm unclear as to how many attributes I can chain together or even how - I am digging through the documentation but some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the text content of your link element, you may try with Cypress command [`cy.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax):

```
cy.contains('a.menubuttontext', "Men's Apparel").click();
```

You can also use a regex for the 2nd argument to fine tune your search.